# Android - How to compile a class which has others activities inside

Tags: android

I have an ExpandableListView which has a lot of children and for every child I would start an activity. Someone told me to create an unique class with all the activities of every children. Is it possible? How? In my project I have a Child.class, a Group.class, a MyExpandableListView.class, a XmlHandler.class and the main activity. I take the name for the ExpandableList from xml files that are in res/raw folder. I hope someone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your activities triggered by the `ExpandableListView`'s child click event are similar (I mean only the data they display is different), it's enough for you to have a single activity, and make it's content dynamic based on the selected (clicked) child of the `ExpandableListView`.

Let's call your new activity `Details`.
If your main activity doesn't extend `ExpandableListActivity`, but you have inside a member of type `MyExpandableListView myExpandableListView`, you should set the `OnChildClickListener on that:

```
final ExpandableListView myExpandableListView = getExpandableListView();
myExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, 
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
    {
        final Child selectedChild = groups.get(groupPosition)
                .getChildren().get(childPosition);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(testactivity.this, Details.class);
        intent.putExtra("selectedChild", selectedChild);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

If your main activity extends `ExpandableListActivity`, to call the `Detail` activity, you need to override the `onChildClick` event of your `ExpandableListActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, 
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
{
    final Child selectedChild = groups.get(groupPosition)
            .getChildren().get(childPosition);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Details.class);
    intent.putExtra("selectedChild", selectedChild);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

You add the clicked child's value as an extra to the `Details` activity's intent by the `putExtra` method, and then just start the activity.

Inside the `Details` activity you can retrieve the passed `Child` (the clicked item on your exp.listactivity) from the activity's `Intent` using the `getSerializableExtra` method (for this to work, your `Child` class must implement `java.io.Serializable`!).
**Details.java**:

```
public class Details extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasExtra("selectedChild"))
        {
            final Child selectedChild = (Child)intent.
                getSerializableExtra("selectedChild");
            if (selectedChild != null)
            {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameText)).
                    setText(selectedChild.getName());
                ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(getResources().
                    getIdentifier(selectedChild.getImage(), "drawable", "com.test.com"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `Details` activity's layout should contain a text and an image
**details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/nameText" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:textSize="30dip" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_below="@id/nameText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By this you can achieve, that when you click on a child item of your `ExpandableListActivity`, you start a new activity (`Details`) where the selected `Child`'s image and text are displayed.

If you put more information inside your `Child` class (or url from where to fetch more data), you can get it more complicated.

Comment: I've got some errors. I can't override the `onChildClick`, I need to remove the override to go on. In `final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Details.class);` I need to remove the Intent's arguments to go on, the result is this `final Intent intent = new Intent ();`. `startActivity(intent);` gives me an error but it goes away only if I create a method like this `private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }`. Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that your main activity extends `ExpandableListActivity`. If it's not, you need to set the listener on your `MyExpandableListView` instance. Please see my update. Remove the `@Override public boolean onChildClick` method, and the `startActivity` method too, stop working in your `MyExpandableListView` class, the listener goes to your `testactivity` class.

Comment: My main activity extends `ExpandableListActivity` but I haven't `onChildClick` event.

Comment: What I would like to do is, maybe, a little more complicated. My layout is different because I want put the informations by myself.

Comment: If you extend `ExpandableListActivity`, your activity has the `onChildClick` method. Make sure to use jdk 1.6 to compile your project, so it won't throw error for the `@override`. Could you please share some different layouts you'd like to use for different child items. (Why are you using explicit `MyExpandableListView` when you extend the `ExpandableListActivity`?)

Comment: Could you please temporarily share your project somewhere (like github), to take a look at it as a whole? There might be architectural problems that prevent you from succeeding. thank you!

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?hf0xz7d0b6bp2ri

As you can see, my layout is `last_layout`, all IDs with number 2 must change about informations I want to put, the IDs without number are the same for all activities.

Comment: First of all, your androidManifest file is messed up, you declared all your classes as activities, which you shouldn't. You should declare there as activity only those classes that extend `Activity` or any subclass of it, that your application wants to show up. I assume these would be (besides your main `testactivity`) `Ingredients`, `SearchDrinks`, `SearchCoctail` and `SearchIngredient`. But your project doesn't contain any of these implementations. You need these activities to be defined in your project, so please share them (and their layouts too). thank you!

Comment: I delete those activities because I didn't finished the activities so they were unnecessary. Thank you for your help. It is possible to use my layout (last_layout) to see informations? And how can I put all the informations inside the layout?

Comment: Please see [this link](http://www.mediafire.com/?yp16z8cdy2jtd7m) for a version of your project with correct manifest, and a sample Details activity that uses your last_layout.xml. I hope it will work.

Comment: Let me know, if still confused, and about what, so I could help.

Comment: I'm confused about how and where put informations for every child to see them in layout. Maybe I need to add informations in data.xml file?

Comment: Exactly. And you shoul modify the XmlHandler class to parse the new information, and the Child class to store it.

Comment: I made a search activity in which there's a spinner and a listview. Why, if I put an intent at the listview listener to go to the same layout that I can see when I tap on a child, I can see only the same layout but without the informations? On the layout there's written only TextView and as image there's my icon.

Comment: This is the intent at the listview listener:                        

`list.setClickable(true); list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {Intent intent = new Intent(Search.this,Details.class); startActivity(intent);}});`

Comment: I think this is an other issue, so you should create an other thread looking for solution (to keep SOF's threads issue-focused and clean). But at the first look, the problem might be with the layout of your child activity.

Comment: Could you take a look?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612232/android-problem-with-layout-and-activity